# В Qt не получается нормально использовать имена классов унаследованных от QObject (ошибка «was not declared in this scope»)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Делаю свои первые шаги в QT. Создал свой класс, в котором понадобилась система сигналов и слотов.

Хэдер класса:

```
class Bs : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    explicit Bs(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}
    inline QTcpServer* GetTcpServer() { return &tcp_server_; }
    public slots:
    ...
    private:
    ...
    signals:
    ...
};
```

Но куда бы я не инклюдил, при попытке обратится по имени (Bs) или использовать в качестве параметра шаблонов выскакивает ошибка на этапе компиляции «… was not declared in this scope». Например если написать `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bs>> bs_list_{};`. Что тут не так?

Компилятор GCC 8.1. Система сборки qmake.

#### UPD: Добавлен код который просил Andrej Levkovitch

```
#pragma once
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include "Protobuf/..."
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include "bs.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

   public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

   private:
    Ui::MainWindow* ui{nullptr};
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bs>> bs_list_{};
    QString server_logs_{};
    std::mutex server_logs_mutex_{};

   private slots:
    void UpdateServerLog(QString in_str);
};
```

#### UPD2: Добавлен скрипт qmake

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-07-27T15:13:43
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui widgets
QT += network

TARGET = SlpServerWithGuiUser
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++17

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    Protobuf/SomeProtocol.pb.cc \
    Encryptor/encryptor.cpp \
    bs.cpp \

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    Protobuf/SomeProtocol.pb.h \
    Encryptor/encryptor.h \
    bs.h \


FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -lprotobuf
LIBS += -lssl -lcrypto

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

#### UPD3: Проблема решена.

Проблема была в том что в MainWindows.h инклюдился bs.h и наоборот. Если честно впервые сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой. Большое спасибо всем кто пытался помочь.

Comment: по этому примеру ничего сказать нельзя, продемонстрируйте где вы хэдэр подключаете

Comment: я вспомнил что заменил стандартные inlude гуарды на #pragma once. Это просто к сведенью.

Comment: 1) проверьте точно ли хэдэр называется `bs.h`, 2) находится ли он в текущей директории

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch 100% да. 10 это всё перепроверил. Статический анализатор всё воспринимает нормально. т.е. он видит класс Bs там где он должен быть.

Comment: Ну так если анализатор видит, то у вас проблема не сдесь, а при сборке - что вы используете?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch qmake. Я в начале написал. С ним я работаю впервые, до этого использовал исключительно CMake поэтому мог тут накосячить.

Comment: из того что вы написали в начале никак нельзя заключить, что проблема в файле сборщика. Особенно когда вы вместо этого файла закинули код. И про то что анализатор все видит тоже не сказали

Comment: если до этого использовали cmake - возвращайтесь к нему. qmake - полный отстой, с этим даже соглашаются те, кто qt написал

Comment: попробуйте слеши убрать после `bs.cpp` и `bs.h` в файле pro

Comment: @BeardedBeaver спасибо, не помогло. Andrej Levkovitch когда в qtcreator выбираешь создать проект QtWiget он перестаёт предлагать систему сборки и ставит меня перед фактом что я должен работать в qmake.

Comment: @mrFieldy в чем проблема написать свой `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Тут файл для qmake простой, проблема не в нем. У меня qmake намного более хитрые проекты отрабатывает спокойно. Что-то не так с самими файлами

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вы так уже делали?

Comment: @mrFieldy я так все время делаю. Более я того, я и `qtcreator` не юзаю

Comment: Вместо этого полотна вам надо было создать *минимальный* пример, воспроизводящий эту проблему. Вот у вас написано "не получается нормально использовать имена классов унаследованных от QObject" - а если не наследовать, то ошибка пропадает? А если убрать все содержимое этого класса? А вообще у вас наверняка либо цикличные инклюды (`Bs.h` включает заголовочный файл, который включает `Bs.h`) либо промашка с пространством имен.

Comment: @VTT да, если его не наследовать то всё хорошо собирается. Сейчас попробую воспроизвести в маленьком коде.

Comment: @VTT Спасибо, проблема была в цикличном инклюде =).